# How to file_save_data with utf encoding?

Tags: 7, files

`file_save_data` is saving files with ANSI encoding. I want `utf8`. How can I specify encoding?

Comment: Looks like the source was ANSI encoded. I changed the source text to utf, and the file saved as utf8. Hint was taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115533/php-file-put-contents-and-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

you do it with UTF8 add BOM

```
file_put_contents($File_name, "\xEF\xBB\xBF".  $content);
```

Comment: Thx, but can I do this with Drupal file_save_data?

Comment: @giorgio79 – [`file_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7.x) accepts three arguments, the first being `$data`, a string containing the contents of the file. So simply do `"\xEF\xBB\xBF" .  $data` as in this answer or `chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) . $data` to prepend the byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning of the string.